# Flutter make a tab bar that picks the first element when user scrolls ( like in Airbnb home page)

Tags: flutter, list, dart, tabs, hybrid-mobile-app

As you can see in the gif here, the tab selects the appropriate item in the seen whenever the user scrolls, unlike the regular tab bar which require click action to change the selected item. Need help pls
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cjhT.gif

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom widget with animation controller , you must have some basic knowledge of animation in flutter .

but if you want to have a look at the code check [this](https://github.com/mahmoudBens/airbnb-flutter-clone) .

Comment: I see But the code dont even implement the scrolling tabs.